# how to maintain session in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, session

I have displayed the login link on the home page. Which links to the login page.

I want when a user login successfully, then instead of that link it should display logout or welcom user.

So my how will I do this? How wordpress maintain sessions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/login-and-out/

Once it's enabled, just add this to your theme where you want the login/logout links to display:
`rh_hype_lilo();`